# Find all positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $1/a + 1/b + 1/c = 4/3999$

Tags: diophantine-equations, contest-math

Find all positive integers $a, b, c$ such that $1/a + 1/b + 1/c = 4/3999$.

The contest is just ended, so you may freely answer. (I did not attend the contest: it is an Italian contest for schools and the groups may ask other people for hints. This is how I got involved, but of course asking on MSE would have been cheating)

I found three solutions: I am explaining below what I did. I would like however to know if there is a more general approach.

Comment: A more general approach? It is a notorious unsolved problem, whether it is true that for every $n$ there exist $a,b,c$ with $4/n=(1/a)+(1/b)+(1/c)$. The problem is attributed to Erdos and Straus.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: thanks for the specification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have more general equation 
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}=\frac{n}{d},$$
where $a,b,c,d,n\in \mathbb{N}$, $a\leqslant b \leqslant c$, ($n<d$), then **search algorithm** can be described as:

**1)** since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}$ is the greater, then $\displaystyle\frac{1}{a}\geqslant\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{n}{d}$. 
 So, we'll consider every $a\in\mathbb{N}$, such that
$$\displaystyle\frac{d}{n} <  a \leqslant \frac{3d}{n}.$$

**2)** since $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b}$ is the 2-nd greater, then $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b}\geqslant\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{n}{d}-\frac{1}{a}\right)$. 
 So, we'll consider every $b\in\mathbb{N}$, $b\geqslant a$, such that  $\displaystyle\left(\frac{n}{d}-\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-1}<  b \leqslant 2 \cdot \left(\frac{n}{d}-\frac{1}{a}\right)^{-1}$,
$$\frac{ad}{an-d} < b \leqslant \frac{2ad}{an-d} .$$

**3)** when we have $a,b$, we consider fraction
$$\frac{n}{d}-\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b},$$
and calculate 2 values (numerator and denominator): 
$$N = abn - bd - ad,$$
$$D = abd.$$

If $N$ divides $D$, then $c=D/N$ is integer, $c\geqslant b$, and we can add triple $(a,b,c)$  to solution list.

---

Using this algorithm, I found 1834 ordered solutions:

1)  $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000} + \frac{1}{3999001} + \frac{1}{15992004999000}$;

2) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{3999002}+\frac{1}{7996004499000}$;

3) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{3999003}+\frac{1}{5330670999000}$;

4) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{3999004}+\frac{1}{3998004249000}$;

5) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{3999005}+\frac{1}{3198404199000}$;

6) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{3999006}+\frac{1}{2665337499000}$;

7) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{3999008}+\frac{1}{1999004124000}$;

...

1832) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2666}+\frac{1}{2666}+\frac{1}{3999}$;

1833) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2666}+\frac{1}{2709}+\frac{1}{3906}$;

1834) $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2924}+\frac{1}{2924}+\frac{1}{3162}$.

Among them (with small $a,b,c$-values) we can find:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{1806}+\frac{1}{4123}+\frac{1}{4902}$,

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2046}+\frac{1}{3311}+\frac{1}{4774}$,

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2193}+\frac{1}{3162}+\frac{1}{4386}$,

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2294}+\frac{1}{3182}+\frac{1}{3999}$,

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2618}+\frac{1}{3162}+\frac{1}{3311}$.

---

More complete list:

```
1) (1000, 3999001, 15992004999000);
2) (1000, 3999002, 7996004499000);
3) (1000, 3999003, 5330670999000);
4) (1000, 3999004, 3998004249000);
5) (1000, 3999005, 3198404199000);
6) (1000, 3999006, 2665337499000);
7) (1000, 3999008, 1999004124000);
8) (1000, 3999009, 1776892999000);
9) (1000, 3999010, 1599204099000);
10) (1000, 3999012, 1332670749000);
11) (1000, 3999015, 1066137399000);
12) (1000, 3999016, 999504061500);
13) (1000, 3999018, 888448499000);
14) (1000, 3999020, 799604049000);
15) (1000, 3999024, 666337374000);
16) (1000, 3999025, 639684039000);
17) (1000, 3999030, 533070699000);
18) (1000, 3999031, 515874999000);
19) (1000, 3999032, 499754030250);
20) (1000, 3999036, 444226249000);
21) (1000, 3999040, 399804024000);
22) (1000, 3999043, 371910999000);
23) (1000, 3999045, 355381799000);
24) (1000, 3999048, 333170686500);
25) (1000, 3999050, 319844019000);
...   ...  ...
660) (1000, 7874000, 8125968);
661) (1000, 7966008, 8030250);
662) (1000, 7998000, 7998000);

663) (1001, 800600, 3204800999400);
664) (1001, 800602, 291346273218);
665) (1001, 800604, 152610333876);
666) (1001, 800606, 103381452174);
667) (1001, 800618, 35218385202);
668) (1001, 800624, 26486752656);
669) (1001, 800646, 13874394534);
670) (1001, 800660, 10647977340);
...  ...  ...
750) (1001, 1436974, 1807806);
751) (1001, 1463462, 1767558);
752) (1001, 1488058, 1732962);

753) (1002, 445223, 198223074506);
754) (1002, 445224, 99111759864);
755) (1002, 445226, 49556102543);
756) (1002, 445253, 6394723586);
757) (1002, 445265, 4610273810);
758) (1002, 445284, 3197584404);
759) (1002, 445308, 2305359516);
760) (1002, 445346, 1599014813);
761) (1002, 445389, 1187407074);
762) (1002, 445394, 1152902369);
763) (1002, 445556, 593926148);
764) (1002, 445890, 297185685);
765) (1002, 446183, 206712266);
766) (1002, 446555, 149149370);
767) (1002, 447071, 107650538);
768) (1002, 447144, 103578744);
769) (1002, 447888, 74797296);
770) (1002, 448920, 54047880);
771) (1002, 449066, 52011983);
772) (1002, 450399, 38734314);
773) (1002, 450554, 37621259);
774) (1002, 452403, 28048986);
775) (1002, 452618, 27246551);
776) (1002, 455576, 19589768);
777) (1002, 459584, 14247104);
778) (1002, 465930, 10017495);
779) (1002, 473111, 7552778);
780) (1002, 473946, 7346163);
781) (1002, 486545, 5242130);
782) (1002, 501000, 3999000);
783) (1002, 502541, 3903458);
784) (1002, 527868, 2843676);
785) (1002, 556778, 2222111);
786) (1002, 559860, 2174340);
787) (1002, 605709, 1680354);
788) (1002, 610514, 1644449);
789) (1002, 667833, 1335666);
790) (1002, 674498, 1309781);
791) (1002, 754005, 1087170);
792) (1002, 766196, 1062788);
793) (1002, 890444, 890444);
794) (1003, 308550, 8088843950);
795) (1003, 308568, 3198101608);
796) (1003, 308760, 429564840);
797) (1003, 308806, 355823022);
798) (1003, 310930, 40109970);
799) (1003, 311406, 33503622);
800) (1003, 314588, 16043988);
801) (1003, 315792, 13432176);
802) (1003, 329902, 4764486);
803) (1003, 362576, 2070192);
804) (1003, 445222, 1005006);
805) (1004, 236191, 3778111236);
806) (1004, 236199, 2450485892);
807) (1004, 236220, 1274761230);
808) (1004, 236285, 513079140);
809) (1004, 236442, 210118124);
810) (1004, 236685, 109872740);
811) (1004, 237446, 44164956);
812) (1004, 238134, 28727452);
813) (1004, 238607, 23183364);
814) (1004, 239940, 15056235);
815) (1004, 251000, 3999000);
816) (1004, 259032, 2676664);
817) (1004, 264554, 2201772);
818) (1004, 279930, 1511020);
819) (1004, 345376, 746976);
820) (1004, 445222, 503004);
821) (1005, 191382, 28487529670);
822) (1005, 191394, 2757030570);
823) (1005, 191436, 662687620);
824) (1005, 191518, 266982270);
825) (1005, 191580, 183980660);
826) (1005, 191620, 153257676);
827) (1005, 191952, 64303920);
828) (1005, 192022, 57305670);
829) (1005, 193440, 17977440);
830) (1005, 193758, 15598270);
831) (1005, 197284, 6395820);
832) (1005, 199950, 4465550);
833) (1005, 201000, 3999000);
834) (1005, 201670, 3751062);
835) (1005, 215946, 1682370);
836) (1005, 218956, 1519620);
837) (1005, 222270, 1377118);
838) (1005, 274164, 633820);
839) (1005, 279930, 605010);
840) (1005, 290780, 559860);
841) (1005, 335670, 445222);
...  ...  ...
1500) (1240, 5520, 79120);
1501) (1240, 5547, 73960);
1502) (1240, 5560, 71724);
1503) (1240, 5590, 67080);
1504) (1240, 5610, 64328);
1505) (1240, 5640, 60630);
1506) (1240, 5676, 56760);
1507) (1240, 5736, 51385);
1508) (1240, 5760, 49536);
1509) (1240, 5805, 46440);
1510) (1240, 5848, 43860);
1511) (1240, 5880, 42140);
1512) (1240, 5934, 39560);
1513) (1240, 5960, 38442);
1514) (1240, 6020, 36120);
1515) (1240, 6060, 34744);
1516) (1240, 6120, 32895);
1517) (1240, 6192, 30960);
1518) (1240, 6235, 29928);
1519) (1240, 6360, 27348);
1520) (1240, 6450, 25800);
1521) (1240, 6536, 24510);
1522) (1240, 6600, 23650);
1523) (1240, 6708, 22360);
1524) (1240, 6760, 21801);
1525) (1240, 6880, 20640);
1526) (1240, 6960, 19952);
1527) (1240, 7009, 19560);
1528) (1240, 7095, 18920);
1529) (1240, 7224, 18060);
1530) (1240, 7310, 17544);
1531) (1240, 7560, 16254);
1532) (1240, 7740, 15480);
1533) (1240, 7912, 14835);
1534) (1240, 8040, 14405);
1535) (1240, 8256, 13760);
1536) (1240, 8385, 13416);
1537) (1240, 8600, 12900);
1538) (1240, 8760, 12556);
1539) (1240, 8858, 12360);
1540) (1240, 9030, 12040);
1541) (1240, 9288, 11610);
1542) (1240, 9460, 11352);
1543) (1240, 9960, 10707);
1544) (1240, 10320, 10320);
1545) (1241, 5160, 1538840);
1546) (1242, 5160, 770040);
1547) (1244, 5160, 385640);
1548) (1245, 5084, 2926580);
1549) (1245, 5160, 308760);
1550) (1247, 5046, 6726318);
1551) (1247, 5084, 613524);
1552) (1247, 5394, 77314);
1553) (1248, 5031, 4990752);
1554) (1248, 5160, 193440);
1555) (1250, 5000, 3999000);
1556) (1250, 5160, 155000);
1557) (1256, 5160, 97340);
1558) (1260, 5160, 78120);
1559) (1262, 4811, 24279856518);
1560) (1265, 5160, 62744);
1561) (1269, 4712, 257119704);
1562) (1271, 4712, 803928);
1563) (1271, 5160, 50840);
1564) (1272, 5160, 49290);
1565) (1275, 4650, 1133050);
1566) (1280, 5160, 39680);
1567) (1290, 4444, 29619260);
1568) (1290, 4445, 11850370);
1569) (1290, 4450, 2965925);
1570) (1290, 4460, 1189036);
1571) (1290, 4464, 959760);
1572) (1290, 4472, 693160);
1573) (1290, 4495, 386570);
1574) (1290, 4515, 279930);
1575) (1290, 4650, 99975);
1576) (1290, 4730, 73315);
1577) (1290, 4960, 42656);
1578) (1290, 5084, 35260);
1579) (1290, 5160, 31992);
1580) (1290, 5332, 26660);
1581) (1290, 5676, 20460);
1582) (1290, 6045, 16770);
1583) (1290, 6665, 13330);
1584) (1290, 7525, 10850);
1585) (1292, 4420, 83959005);
1586) (1296, 4374, 46644336);
1587) (1296, 4464, 215946);
1588) (1299, 4340, 80806460);
1589) (1302, 4308, 13399316);
1590) (1302, 4309, 7782054);
1591) (1302, 4326, 961093);
1592) (1302, 4340, 559860);
1593) (1302, 4515, 93310);
1594) (1302, 4774, 43989);
1595) (1302, 5160, 26040);
1596) (1302, 5859, 16254);
1597) (1302, 7224, 10664);
1598) (1302, 7998, 9331);
1599) (1304, 5160, 25265);
1600) (1320, 4123, 7549080);
1601) (1320, 4125, 3999000);
1602) (1320, 4128, 2346080);
1603) (1320, 4730, 31992);
1604) (1320, 5160, 20460);
1605) (1323, 4092, 77596596);
1606) (1330, 4085, 279930);
1607) (1330, 4123, 171570);
1608) (1333, 4000, 15996000);
1609) (1333, 4002, 5334666);
1610) (1333, 4008, 1780888);
1611) (1333, 4030, 519870);
1612) (1333, 4042, 375906);
1613) (1333, 4092, 175956);
1614) (1333, 4128, 127968);
1615) (1333, 4278, 61318);
1616) (1333, 4386, 45322);
1617) (1333, 4960, 20640);
1618) (1333, 5332, 15996);
1619) (1333, 5848, 12648);
1620) (1333, 6882, 9546);
1621) (1333, 7998, 7998);
1622) (1334, 3999, 1778222);
1623) (1336, 4008, 445222);
1624) (1340, 5160, 16616);
1625) (1344, 3904, 18214112);
1626) (1344, 3906, 5374656);
1627) (1348, 3870, 80859780);
1628) (1350, 3870, 899775);
1629) (1359, 3782, 221008734);
1630) (1364, 3744, 54898272);
1631) (1364, 3751, 1935516);
1632) (1364, 3784, 351912);
1633) (1364, 3999, 58652);
1634) (1364, 4092, 43989);
1635) (1364, 5160, 13640);
1636) (1368, 3720, 2279430);
1637) (1376, 3658, 7550112);
1638) (1376, 3720, 213280);
1639) (1376, 3744, 155961);
1640) (1376, 3999, 42656);
1641) (1376, 4128, 31992);
1642) (1376, 6192, 8928);
1643) (1386, 3612, 527868);
1644) (1386, 3906, 43989);
1645) (1395, 3530, 8469882);
1646) (1395, 3534, 2279430);
1647) (1395, 3870, 39990);
1648) (1395, 5160, 11160);
1649) (1400, 3500, 3999000);
1650) (1400, 5160, 10850);
1651) (1410, 3440, 3007248);
1652) (1419, 3384, 49619592);
1653) (1419, 3410, 439890);
1654) (1419, 3526, 83886);
1655) (1419, 3784, 31992);
1656) (1426, 3348, 3311172);
1657) (1426, 3354, 1195701);
1658) (1434, 3311, 1140986);
1659) (1440, 5160, 8928);
1660) (1442, 3311, 210738);
1661) (1450, 3225, 1932850);
1662) (1452, 3311, 105028);
1663) (1462, 3163, 10001406);
1664) (1462, 3164, 5002284);
1665) (1462, 3165, 3335910);
1666) (1462, 3166, 2502723);
1667) (1462, 3168, 1669536);
1668) (1462, 3171, 1114078);
1669) (1462, 3174, 836349);
1670) (1462, 3179, 591294);
1671) (1462, 3180, 558620);
1672) (1462, 3193, 325686);
1673) (1462, 3196, 297228);
1674) (1462, 3198, 280891);
1675) (1462, 3213, 199206);
1676) (1462, 3224, 164424);
1677) (1462, 3230, 150195);
1678) (1462, 3255, 110670);
1679) (1462, 3264, 101184);
1680) (1462, 3286, 83793);
1681) (1462, 3315, 68510);
1682) (1462, 3348, 56916);
1683) (1462, 3366, 52173);
1684) (1462, 3441, 38998);
1685) (1462, 3451, 37758);
1686) (1462, 3468, 35836);
1687) (1462, 3534, 30039);
1688) (1462, 3689, 22134);
1689) (1462, 3720, 21080);
1690) (1462, 3740, 20460);
1691) (1462, 3774, 19499);
1692) (1462, 4029, 14694);
1693) (1462, 4123, 13566);
1694) (1462, 4216, 12648);
1695) (1462, 4278, 12121);
1696) (1462, 4318, 11811);
1697) (1462, 4743, 9486);
1698) (1462, 4896, 8928);
1699) (1462, 5084, 8364);
1700) (1462, 5270, 7905);
1701) (1462, 5763, 7006);
1702) (1462, 6045, 6630);
1703) (1462, 6324, 6324);
1704) (1463, 3162, 2138906);
1705) (1464, 3162, 1070184);
1706) (1466, 3162, 535823);
1707) (1479, 3162, 127194);
1708) (1488, 3047, 64986416);
1709) (1488, 3048, 8125968);
1710) (1488, 3053, 1514288);
1711) (1488, 3056, 1018412);
1712) (1488, 3096, 191952);
1713) (1488, 3311, 38192);
1714) (1488, 3440, 26660);
1715) (1488, 3596, 19952);
1716) (1488, 5160, 7440);
1717) (1496, 3162, 64328);
1718) (1497, 3010, 46561690);
1719) (1498, 3010, 2139465);
1720) (1500, 3000, 3999000);
1721) (1503, 3006, 445222);
1722) (1505, 2978, 416815770);
1723) (1505, 3010, 279930);
1724) (1505, 3096, 78120);
1725) (1505, 3162, 51170);
1726) (1519, 2940, 559860);
1727) (1530, 3162, 32895);
1728) (1540, 3311, 20460);
1729) (1542, 2843, 1947915566);
1730) (1548, 2823, 45156708);
1731) (1548, 2826, 2511372);
1732) (1548, 2838, 527868);
1733) (1548, 2852, 275931);
1734) (1548, 3096, 31992);
1735) (1548, 3162, 26316);
1736) (1548, 4128, 8928);
1737) (1550, 2825, 903774);
1738) (1550, 2838, 366575);
1739) (1550, 5160, 6200);
1740) (1560, 2790, 1247688);
1741) (1560, 2795, 693160);
1742) (1560, 5160, 6045);
1743) (1581, 2720, 10877280);
1744) (1581, 2754, 215946);
1745) (1600, 2666, 6398400);
1746) (1602, 2666, 1067733);
1747) (1608, 2643, 629463928);
1748) (1608, 2881, 31992);
1749) (1612, 2666, 207948);
1750) (1624, 2604, 2164792);
1751) (1625, 2600, 3999000);
1752) (1634, 2580, 1519620);
1753) (1634, 2666, 75981);
1754) (1634, 3162, 13889);
1755) (1640, 5084, 5160);
1756) (1642, 2556, 2797268508);
1757) (1650, 2537, 43255850);
1758) (1650, 3311, 10850);
1759) (1662, 2509, 5558554014);
1760) (1670, 2505, 445222);
1761) (1674, 2484, 3311172);
1762) (1674, 2511, 215946);
1763) (1674, 2666, 35991);
1764) (1674, 4644, 5332);
1765) (1675, 2480, 107173200);
1766) (1677, 2480, 1386320);
1767) (1677, 2666, 34658);
1768) (1677, 3224, 10664);
1769) (1680, 2480, 559860);
1770) (1692, 2444, 14660334);
1771) (1705, 2418, 5718570);
1772) (1705, 2420, 1935516);
1773) (1720, 2388, 10610680);
1774) (1720, 2408, 279930);
1775) (1720, 2480, 63984);
1776) (1720, 2580, 31992);
1777) (1720, 3720, 6665);
1778) (1726, 2376, 2733300504);
1779) (1736, 2408, 111972);
1780) (1736, 2418, 93912);
1781) (1736, 3311, 8184);
1782) (1736, 4340, 5160);
1783) (1740, 2350, 181687900);
1784) (1751, 3162, 8858);
1785) (1754, 2325, 58452050);
1786) (1762, 2311, 16283856018);
1787) (1767, 2356, 101308);
1788) (1776, 2294, 789136);
1789) (1798, 2262, 502541);
1790) (1800, 2250, 3999000);
1791) (1806, 2240, 8957760);
1792) (1806, 2310, 73315);
1793) (1806, 2408, 31992);
1794) (1806, 2604, 15996);
1795) (1806, 4123, 4902);
1796) (1820, 2236, 279930);
1797) (1829, 2232, 182664);
1798) (1832, 2201, 16779288);
1799) (1846, 2201, 238134);
1800) (1855, 2170, 2967258);
1801) (1860, 2170, 559860);
1802) (1860, 2580, 13330);
1803) (1860, 3720, 5160);
1804) (1892, 2120, 93256680);
1805) (1892, 2365, 20460);
1806) (1900, 2110, 1603199100);
1807) (1925, 2080, 3202399200);
1808) (1935, 2070, 2759310);
1809) (1935, 2790, 7998);
1810) (1938, 2108, 101308);
1811) (1939, 2064, 41354992);
1812) (1958, 2046, 1305007);
1813) (1984, 2016, 5374656);
1814) (1984, 2064, 85312);
1815) (1984, 2112, 43989);
1816) (1984, 2666, 8256);
1817) (2000, 2000, 3999000);
1818) (2004, 2004, 445222);
1819) (2015, 3224, 5160);
1820) (2040, 3162, 5160);
1821) (2046, 2046, 43989);
1822) (2046, 3311, 4774);
1823) (2064, 2064, 31992);
1824) (2064, 2107, 24304);
1825) (2193, 3162, 4386);
1826) (2201, 2840, 5160);
1827) (2232, 2790, 5160);
1828) (2236, 2580, 6045);
1829) (2294, 3182, 3999);
1830) (2480, 2480, 5160);
1831) (2618, 3162, 3311);
1832) (2666, 2666, 3999);
1833) (2666, 2709, 3906);
1834) (2924, 2924, 3162).
```

Comment: gosh :-) Let's say that the problem was not well posed.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that $3999 = 3 \times 31 \times 43$ and so I started to search solutions for the auxiliary equation $$\frac{h}{a} + \frac{k}{b} + \frac{l}{c} = 4$$
where the terms $h, k, l$ may be 1 or a factor of 3999.

If $\frac{h}{a} = 3$, I may set $\frac{k}{b}$ and $\frac{l}{c}$ both equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and so a solution is $$ \frac{1}{1333} + \frac{1}{7998} + \frac{1}{7998}$$.

If $\frac{h}{a} = 1$, I may set $\frac{k}{b}$ and $\frac{l}{c}$ both equal to $\frac{3}{2}$, leading to $$\frac{1}{3999} + \frac{1}{2666} + \frac{1}{2666}$$

but I may also set $\frac{k}{b}= \frac{3 \times 31}{32} = \frac{93}{32}$ and $\frac{l}{c} =\frac{3}{32}$, obtaining $$\frac{1}{3999} + \frac{1}{1376} + \frac{1}{42656}$$

Egyptian fractions are not limited to a fixed number of terms, so I am not sure they can be used to find all possible answers.

Comment: Try \frac{a}{b} instead of a/b (between dollar signs, of course) for fractions: it makes things much clearer. Also try *double* dollar signs to center things and make them bigger.